# How can I replace a data.table column with a sequence that depends on another column?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two columns `ID` and `Trial`. The ID column is filled with *NA*s. The `Trial` column starts at 0 and ends on an arbritary number (e.g. 1232), whereupon the next trial sequences commences with 0, etc. My goal is to create a unique ID for each series of trials.

I am new to R and realize that there are several ways to solve this:

- Using two nested loops
- Using `lapply` (or `rapply`?) together with an abstract (?) function call or handle
- Using `nextElem` from the `iterator` package together with point 1 or 2
- Generating the list first and replacing the
  values in a second step, e.g. using two `seq()` based on some kind of iteration on subsets: `ex_data[subset]`

So far, I have figured out that number of participants is:

```
N <- dim(filter(ex_data, Trial == 0))[1]
```

Or more elegantly:

```
N <- count(ex_data[Trial == 0])
```

In particular, it is the conditional part that I am struggling with and what would be the most R-like solution.

Pseudocode:

```
IDs are 1:N

while IDs < N+1
    current + 1
    while column Trial is > 0
        ID is IDs[current]
        next Trial
    next Trial
```

How do I make the decision when to use loops over more compact expressions like the `apply` family? Specifically, how do I generate a new sequence based on a nearly cyclic column?

```
Example Data (for generation see below)


      id  t
 [1,] NA  0
 [2,] NA  1
 [3,] NA  2
 [4,] NA  3
 [5,] NA  4
 [6,] NA  5
 [7,] NA  0
 [8,] NA  1
 [9,] NA  2
[10,] NA  3
[11,] NA  4
[12,] NA  5
[13,] NA  6
[14,] NA  7
[15,] NA  0
[16,] NA  1
[17,] NA  2
[18,] NA  3
[19,] NA  4
[20,] NA  5
[21,] NA  6
[22,] NA  7
[23,] NA  8
[24,] NA  9
[25,] NA 10
[26,] NA 11
[27,] NA 12


# Generate Example Data
t <- c(0:5, 0:7, 0:12)
id <- rep(NA, length(t))
dta <- cbind(id, t)
# Optional (using dtplyr)
# dta <- tbl_df(dta)
```

Comment: add a sample data , so a new series is indicated by '0' right?

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: `ex_data$ID <- cumsum(ex_data$Trial==0 )` would work unless your data meant something else

Comment: Brilliant! @joel.wilson I knew there had to be a simpler solution.

Comment: @akrun Added example data

Comment: you have shared a matrix in the sample

Comment: @joel.wilson Perhaps you did not scroll down to these lines:

# Optional (using dtplyr)
# dta <- tbl_df(dta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution :

```
ex_data$ID <- cumsum(ex_data$Trial==0 )
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
ex_data[, ID := cumsum(!Trial)]
```

Comment: This is an *elegant*, both proper `data.table` solution and a *hack* that operates on a truth table as `FALSE` in R is equivalent to 0. However, it does not generalize to trials that start on, let's say, 1. Also, it works for `dtplyr` dt:s, but not sure how to make it work for df:s...

Comment: @noumenal I am not sure I understand how you wanted it.  Perhaps `dta %>% mutate(id = cumsum(t==first(t)))` or `ex_data[, ID := cumsum(Trial==Trial[1L])]` from `data.table`

Comment: Thanks for your pateience. I like your answer, but I'm afraid Mr Wilson beat you to it. // I'm taking notes of the `data.table` notation, the explicit `L`ong integer format, and `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: @noumenal  It's okay.  Thanks for your comments.  I am not really into points.

Comment: @noumenal `L` does not refer to long int, just to int, an R class and storage format. To my knowledge, big/long int formats are only available via packages like bit64.

Comment: @noumenal Dunno, never figured it out but that sounds plausible :)